# MySQL matching partial strings with LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying create a MySQL query which will return a row (or more, but I'm only interested in a single row) an area suggestion when provided with a postcode.

So, I have a table like so

```
area_id | postcode_start
1       | NE
2       | DL
3       | DL1
4       | DL2
5       | DL6
...
```

And I wish to provide a postcode, for example DL5 8TB and for it to return the row `1 | DL` as the first characters match.

Another example `DL6 4GH` would return two rows, `5 | DL6` and `2 | DL`

```
SELECT *
    FROM (`area_postcodes`)
    WHERE CONCAT(LOWER(`area_postcodes`.`postcode_start`),'%')
        LIKE 'dl5 8tb';
```

Apparently it's a valid query but it always returns an empty set.

You'll see I've added the wildcard `%` to the other side of the query but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know where else to even consider guessing how to go about it, it's almost like the reverse of a normal MySQL LIKE query.

Comment: Is there something magical with prefixes with length 2 (i.e. why wouldn't `DL6 4GH` and `DL5 8TB` both match all of area_id 2,3,4,5? -- all of which have `D` as a prefix)

Comment: No, I'd like all the characters under postcode start to match, so `DL5 4UH` would only match `DL` but `DL6 7HG` would match both `DL` and `DL6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    area_postcodes
WHERE
    'dl5 8tb' LIKE CONCAT(postcode_start, '%');
```

Comment: This seems to be working, thanks so much. Who'd have thought you could put the column on the right //fffffff